# Wordpress Feed JSON plugin - Blog crashes randomly

Tags: json, wordpress, feed

We have two blogs (network set up) on which we use the Feed JSON plugin, 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/feed-json/. For some reason, which we can't see, sometimes the blogs (and the server) crash randomly, and the only thing that fixes it, is deactivate and activate again the Feed JSON plugin. Please, keep in mind that we do use the JSON feeds extensively. We are running a separate site that pulls lots of JSON feeds from our blogs, and we have thousands of users every day. Normally, the numbers shouldn't be a problem. Can you please advise? Has anyone experienced any similar issues?

FYI, the only thing we have customised on the plugin, is just add a couple more fields, that's all. We did that in the ./wp-content/plugins/feed-json/template/feed-json.php file.

This is the gist for the custom fields:
https://gist.github.com/ialexop/7ea41508d194befd0e37

Comment: Try another plugin? This one isn't as actively developed as the one you are using but it might be worth comparing it to -> https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/

Comment: That could be a good idea McNab, indeed, definitely worth looking into. Thanks!